# Updating n-th Row in Table with 'n-th child': on first row there is an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table looks like this,

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    (etc)
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To update the i-th row (var. rowIndex) with my custom HTML, using jQuery, I use

```
$("table#tableID  tr:nth-child(" + (rowIndex) + ")").html(html);
```

The 'nth-child' was the solution I found somewhere here on StackOverflow.

This works **but only for non-1st rows**. On the **first** row, an error happens: **The identical row is updated *both* in row 1 and in the THEAD header.** Thus, both the header row and Row 1 have the same entries.

All other row updates are fine, they update correctly.

Comment: The `<th>` are closed incorrect. Change `</th1>` to `</th>`

Comment: Sorry corrected now - I was just typing to show the HTML structure. That's fixed in the OP now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the tbody in your selector

`$("tableID tbody tr:nth-child(" + (rowIndex) + ")").html(html);`

Comment: Thank you - actually, small typo because of my original post, it's table#tableID. Maybe you want to correct it here also. Thanks